# Waiting for event to be handled

Tags: c#, events, wait

I have a function, let's call it Func1 and `it contains` Func2 & event handler.

Now what I would like to achieve is `not let` function (Func1) return value till Func2 fires and handles event.

Basically Func1 has string as return value and string value is set inside event handler. So I need to wait for event to be handled and then return value.

Code Example

```
    public static string Fun1 ()
    {
        string stringToReturn = String.Empty;
        Func2(); //Func2 will after few sec fire event bellow 

        example.MyEvent += (object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) =>
                               {
                                   stringToReturn = "example"; //this wont be hardcoded
                               };

        //wait for event to be handled and then return value
        return stringToReturn;
    }
```

Comment: Does Func2 run on another thread than Func1?

Answer (score 8):

You could use the [`AutoResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) class. Instantiate it with `var evt = new AutoResetEvent(false);`, call `evt.WaitOne()` where you want to wait, and `evt.Set();` where you want to signal that the waiting code may proceed.

If you have many "wait until" situations that involve events, you could also look into [Reactive Extensions (Rx)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609).

Comment: To be honest I didnt manage to implement it successfully. After adding it to code Finc1 never get to line which returns value

Comment: @Toni: Where did you put the calls to `evt.WaitOne()` and `evt.Set()`? Are you sure that you call both methods on the same instance of `AutoResetEvent` (this is crucial)?

Comment: I'm (at least I think so) I'll try example from MSND on separate project and check what's going on

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't a simple semaphore suffice?

```
public static string Fun1 ()
{
    Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1,1);

    string stringToReturn = String.Empty;
    Func2(); //Func2 will after few sec fire event bellow 

    example.MyEvent += (object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) =>
                           {
                               stringToReturn = "example"; //this wont be hardcoded
                               sem.Release();
                           };
    sem.WaitOne();

    //wait for event to be handled and then return value
    return stringToReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As `Func2` runs on the same thread as `Func1`, `Func1` will not return before `Func2` returns. This means it is guaranteed that the event fired in `Func2` is getting fired before it returns control to `Func1`. Just attach your event handler before calling `Func2` and it should work as expected.

Using a `Semaphore` or an `AutoResetEvent` is overkill in this scenario as both acquire OS resources to manage thread synchronization.